# Rendering React components with promises inside the render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, q

I have a component which gets a collection of items as props and `map`s them to a collection of components which are rendered as children of a parent component. We use images stored in `WebSQL` as byte arrays. Within the `map` function I get an image Id from the item and make an async call to the `DAL` in order to get the byte array for the image. My problem is that I cannot propagate the promise in to React, since it was not designed to deal with promises in rendering (not as far as I can tell anyway). I come from a `C#` background, so I guess I'm looking for something like the `await` keyword for resync-ing branched code.

The `map` function looks something like this (simplified):

```
var items = this.props.items.map(function (item) {
        var imageSrc = Utils.getImageUrlById(item.get('ImageId')); // <-- this contains an async call
        return (
            <MenuItem text={item.get('ItemTitle')}
                      imageUrl={imageSrc} />
       );
    });
```

and the `getImageUrlById` method looks like this:

```
getImageUrlById(imageId) {
    return ImageStore.getImageById(imageId).then(function (imageObject) { //<-- getImageById returns a promise
       var completeUrl = getLocalImageUrl(imageObject.StandardConImage);
       return completeUrl;
    });
}
```

This doesn't work, but I don't know what I need to modify to make this work. I tried adding another promise to the chain, but then I get an error because my render function return a promise instead of legal JSX. I was thinking that maybe I need to leverage one of the `React` life-cycle methods to fetch the data, but since I need the `props` to already be there, I can't figure out where I can do this.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`render()` method should render UI from `this.props` and `this.state`, so to asynchronously load data, you can use `this.state` to store `imageId: imageUrl` mapping.

Then in your `componentDidMount()` method, you can populate `imageUrl` from `imageId`. Then the `render()` method should be pure and simple by rendering the `this.state` object

Note that the `this.state.imageUrls` is populated asynchronously, so the rendered image list item will appear one by one after its url is fetched. You can also initialize the `this.state.imageUrls` with all image id or index (without urls), this way you can show a loader when that image is being loaded.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        imageUrls: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.items.map((item) => {
        ImageStore.getImageById(item.imageId).then(image => {
            const mapping = {id: item.imageId, url: image.url};
            const newUrls = this.state.imageUrls.slice();
            newUrls.push(mapping);

            this.setState({ imageUrls: newUrls });
        })
    });
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.imageUrls.map(mapping => (
            <div>id: {mapping.id}, url: {mapping.url}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. The only thing I would change here (for my use at least) is to do this in `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount` in order to not have an initial "empty" render. `componentWillMount` runs before the initial render.

Comment: @Wint There is an error on this line: `var newUrls = self.state.imageUrls.slice().push(mapping)` because the value returned is not a shallow copy of the array but the length of the new array. See [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Syntax)

Comment: @Wint, very new to react so please forgive my lack of understanding, but I have a few questions: (1) This seems like a performance land mine. Is react friendly to timers or caching for some later iteration to reduce times that the array is cloned? (in Ember we have the run loop to schedule, not sure if there's an equivalent in React)  (2) This seems like it will return something in the order that the async operations complete. Do you recommend any strategies to preserve order?

Answer (score 38):

Or you can use react-promise :

Install the package :

```
npm i react-promise
```

And your code will look something like so :

```
import Async from 'react-promise'

var items = this.props.items.map(function (item) {
    var imageSrc = Utils.getImageUrlById(item.get('ImageId')); // <-- this contains an async call
    return (
        <Async promise={imageSrc} then={(val) => <MenuItem text={item.get('ItemTitle')} imageUrl={val}/>} />    
    );
});
```

**Edit: Oct 2019**

The last build of react-promise provide a hook called `usePromise`:

```js
import usePromise from 'react-promise';

const ExampleWithAsync = (props) => {
  const {value, loading} = usePromise<string>(prom)
  if (loading) return null
  return <div>{value}</div>}
}
```

Full docs: [react-promise](https://github.com/capaj/react-promise)