# Trying to implement a SIMPLE promise in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

Just trying out Promises for the first time in React. I have a basic promise working (ripped from someone else's code), but don't know how to adapt it to be useful.

What I have so far (within my `render()` function)

```
  var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

     let name = 'Dave'

     if (name === 'Dave') {
        resolve("Promise resolved successfully");
     }
     else {
        reject(Error("Promise rejected"));
     }
  });

  promise.then(function(result) {
     console.log(result); // "Promise resolved successfully"
  }, err => {
     console.log(err); // Error: "Promise rejected"
  });
```

Sure enough, as the promise conditional is matched (`name === 'Dave'`), my console logs `Promise resolved successfully`.

However, I don't know how to assign a value to a variable when using the promise. For example:

```
  promise.then(function(result) {
     var newName = 'Bob'
  }, function(err) {
     var newName = 'Anonymous'
  });
```

And then when I try to return this value in `render()`'s return statement, like so:

```
<h2>{newName}</h2>
```

It says newName is undefined.

I have also tried:

```
  promise.then(function(result) {
     var newName = result
  }, function(err) {
     var newName = error
  });
```

...expecting this would assign the `resolve` or `error` string into `newName` variable, but nope.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? How can I make this more useful than just logging a string when my conditional is met?

Any help would be appreciated, because this is really making my head hurt...

---

### Update

```
 render() {

      var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

         let name = 'Paul'

         if (name === 'Paul') {
            resolve("Promise resolved successfully");
         }
         else {
            reject(Error("Promise rejected"));
         }
      });

      let obj = {newName: ''};

      promise.then( result => {
         obj["newName"] = result
      }, function(error) {
         obj["newName"] = error
      });

      console.log(obj.newName)

    return (
      <div className="App">
         <h1>Hello World</h1>
         <h2>{obj.newName}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: For starters, you're declaring a new variable in each of those functions. You would need to declare `newName` outside of your callbacks in order for them to refer to the same variable.

Comment: try `(result) => { ... ` might get you the right closure context

Comment: @MeirionHughes What difference would that make? They aren't even using `this`.

Comment: @MikeC, please see update...

Comment: @Paulos3000 You're still declaring `newName` inside of your callbacks. `var newName` declares a new variable. That's what `var` does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering React components with promises inside the render method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33242378/1048572)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are using `React` in a wrong way. A `Promise` is designed to return result at a later point of time. By the time your promise has been `resolved` or `rejected`, your `render` would have finished execution and it wont update when the promise completes.

`render` method should only depend on `props` and/or `state` to render the desired output. Any change to `prop` or `state` would `re-render` your component.

- First, identify where your `Promise` should go in the life cycle of the component([here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html))
- In your case i would do the following

  - Initialize an state inside your constructor(ES6) or via `getInitialState`

    ```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        name: '',
      };
    }
    ```
  - Then on `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` which ever suits you, call the promise there

    ```
    componentWillMount() {
     var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      let name = 'Paul'

      if (name === 'Paul') {
       resolve("Promise resolved successfully");
      }
      else {
       reject(Error("Promise rejected"));
      }
     });

     let obj = {newName: ''};

     promise.then( result => {
      this.setState({name: result});
     }, function(error) {
      this.setState({name: error});
     });
    }
    ```
  - Then in `render` method write something similar to this.

    ```
    render() {
     return (
      <div className="App">
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
       <h2>{this.state.name}</h2>
      </div>
     );
    }
    ```

Comment: That worked! I actually tried that before but it didn't return the correct state value, not sure why. Maybe a typo/syntax error... Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to be thinking about the scope you're in. When you are in the function you're passing to `promise.then`, you are in a new block scope and therefore any var you create in the function won't exist outside of it's scope. I'm not sure how you're defining your React components, but assuming you have a `newName` variable on your component, there are two ways you could solve the scope problem - bind and arrow functions:

```
promise.then(function(result) {
  this.newName = result; //or what you want to assign it to
}.bind(this))
```

and then you could reference it using `{this.newName}`

Or with an arrow function:

```
promise.then((result) => {
  this.newName = result; //or what you want to assign it to
}.bind(this))
```

I would recommend watching [this egghead video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-the-this-keyword-introduction-and-implicit-binding) to help you understand the `this` keyword in javascript.