# conditional rendering in react native with AsyncStore failure

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using React-Native with Redux, where I want to render a button if the logged in user is eligible. Somehow the button is not showing!

For storing data I'm using [react-native-simple-store](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store)

```
renderIfEligible(toRender) {
  const building = this.props.building;
  const timings = this.props.timings;

  if (building && timings) {
    store.get(storage.userKey).then(user => {
      if (user != null) {
        if (building.submitter.includes(this.props.userId)) {
          console.log('RENDER');  // THIS IS PRINTED OUT IN THE BROWSER
          return toRender;
        }
      } else {
        console.log('NO RENDER');
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}

// Function call
{this.renderIfEligible(
   <Button style={{marginTop: 20}} small danger transparent onPress={() => alert("delete")}><Icon name="trash" /></Button>)}
```

Any idea why the button is not showing up although the console.log() is working?

### Update 1

I've added

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { showButton: false};
}
  ....
renderIfEligible(toRender){
  self = this;
  if (building.submitter.includes(this.props.userId)) {
    self.setState({ showButton: true});
  } else {
    self.setState({ showButton: false});
  }
```

Comment: Maybe `return (toRender)`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma nope.

Comment: So, can you add more code to try to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this button to render correctly based on the [react-native-simple-store](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store) you will need to initialize the value you expect to get from `store.get(storage.userKey)` in your component for an initial render and then in `componentDidMount` call the `store.get()` method to get the `userKey` and set that into that same value that you defaulted. Here's a small example.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isEligible: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    store.get(storage.userKey).then(user => {
      if (user !== null) { // add to this if statement any other checks you need
        this.setState({ isEligible: true });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { building, timings } = this.props;
    const { isEligible } = this.state;

    if (building && timings && isEligible) {
      return (
        <Button ... />
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Basically you just need to give the component a default state until you have the correct data. For this example the default state is that the component returns nothing. I believe, as a general rule, React renders need to be synchronous and so if you need to fetch data asynchronously in order to render correctly you just need to send the component back through the render lifecycle again when the value from the asynchronous query resolves.

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` is not showing up because `store.get(storage.userKey)` is [returning a `promise`](https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store/blob/master/docs/index.md#getkey) of a `user` object which is then being mapped into a component (or `false`) using the `then` function.

As you aren't returning the result of the `then` function, the result of `renderIfEligible` is always `undefined` (your `returns` are for the lambda function).

Unfortunately for you, just changing the function to `return store.get(storage.userKey).then(user => {...})` wont help you as then it will be returning a `promise` of a component (or `false`), which is still unable to be rendered.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33242831/6902543) for ideas on how to get around this.

Comment: I've tried this approach (kind of) before putting this to Stackoverflow, without saving the `this` to a const. But it didn't help :-(