# How to export object based on conditions in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise

I want to export an objects `based on conditions` for example first I check some which language stored in 'AsyncStorage' then based on languages I return a particular `object`.

**file**: `lang.js`

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
let exportingLang = {};

AsyncStorage.getItem('@lang').then(language=> {
    if(language){
        if(language === "hindi") exportingLang = {
           name: 'a hindi name'
        };
        else if(language === "panjabi") exportingLang = {
           name: 'a panjabi name'
        };
        else exportingLang = {
           name: 'a english name'
        };;
    }
});

export const Lang = exportingLang;
```

**file**: `post.js`

```
import {Lang} from 'lang';

export default Post = props => {

    return (
        <Text>{Lang.name}</Text>
    );
}
```

but the above code does not work.

Comment: You definitely need to provide some more information on where you're running that piece of code, etc. Just on its own, that piece of code will never work.

Comment: @AfrazHussain, I have edited my question please have a look at it

Comment: Thank you, seems like you want the response from a JavaScript promise into your render. Let me just come up with a simple answer for you.

Comment: Please select an answer for the question if the answers below have solved it.

Comment: It is working after first `render` but actually I need before `first render` and I voted up ur answr

Comment: Please check out the last comment from my answer. It has a link that shows you how to use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` to get your value before the first render.

Comment: I am using hooks

Comment: That definitely would not be possible with hooks as described in the answers and their comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note here is that `getItem` returns a JavaScript `Promise` according to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/LEGACY/docs/API.md#getitem). With the way JavaScript works, we cannot get the values out of Promises and export them, without *resolving* or *rejecting* the Promise, more on that [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261). To explain it in terms of your example, you could assign a value to the exportingLang, but it will almost certainly return the initial empty object `{}` that you initialized it to because the Promise assignment happens asynchronously, that is, it needs to wait for the storage system to find the `@lang` key, then return its value which can take a while (hence the need for a Promise).

If the point of having the `lang.js` file is to avoid typing the if statements over and over again, then that's all fine (otherwise I would just use the `getItem` Promise once in the Component I need the value in). I would first make sure that we export the results returned from the Promise as follows:

*lang.js*

```
export default AsyncStorage.getItem('@lang').then(language => {
  let exportingLang = {name: 'default'};
  if (language) {
    if (language === 'hindi')
      exportingLang = {
        name: 'a hindi name',
      };
    else if (language === 'panjabi')
      exportingLang = {
        name: 'a panjabi name',
      };
    else
      exportingLang = {
        name: 'a english name',
      };
  }
  return exportingLang;
});
```

This would in-turn give me another Promise as an export.

Secondly, you cannot use values directly from a Promise into a React render method. You need to assign it to a state using `useState` or `useEffect`. You can read more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242378/rendering-react-components-with-promises-inside-the-render-method).

For simplicity's sake, I have used it in a `Component` as follows:

```
import langPromise from './lang';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    lang: { name: '' },
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const lang = await langPromise.then(lang => this.setState({ lang }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.lang.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I've also created a working snack for you at: https://snack.expo.io/rySQiEgIU Please note that this might have the older version of the `AsyncStorage` but the idea is still the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I actually need something before render instead of after render, here as you worked I can access the object after render that I dont want.

Comment: Afraz's answer is quite elegant - I like it.  My answer below accomplishes the same thing.  What do you mean you want to access the object "before render" instead of after render?  In both of these answer, the component renders, and once your AsyncStorage function returns a value, it causes a state change which causes a rerender.  Where in the component lifecycle do you envision needing the value that AsyncStorage returns?

Comment: @Muhammad Unfortunately, you cannot stop a component from rendering and make it wait for the Promise to return a value, exactly as Seth has explained in his comment above. I had also linked a perfect SO question in my answer regarding the same issue. *IF you're still not convinced and you really have to get your value before render then you can use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` to have your async method in.* I absolutely wouldn't recommend it, but you can read more about that in this perfect blog: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data

Answer (score 1):

Why not store the value of `exportingLang` in state, and then use that in your component?

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default Post = props => {

    const [name, setName] = useState()

    AsyncStorage.getItem('@lang').then(language=> {
        if(language){
            if(language === "hindi") {
               setName('a hindi name')
            } else if(language === "panjabi") {
               setName('a punjabi name')
            } else {
               setName('an english name')
            };
        }
    });


    return (
        <Text>{name}</Text>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this happens after render but I need before render access the object