# Return JSX from async arrow function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, arrow-functions

It must be basic but please help me understand why this doesn't work.

When I write a normal arrow function and return jsx, it works. But, when I use async/await request with the same arrow function to return jsx, it fails.

**Edit:**

Actually I have to show profile images of users inside a list view. So, I am calling this function to retrieve the images of the respective users inside my `render() {return }` block

**This works**

```
handleProfilePhoto = firstName => {
        return (
            <img
                className="comment-img"
                src={require("../../../../Webroot/images/dashboard/image3.png")}
                alt={firstName + " profile"}
            />
        );
    };
```

**And this doesn't**

```
handleProfilePhoto = async (firstName) => {
        let err = false;

        await Axios
            .get(MY_URL)
            .then(function () {
                err = false;
            })
            .catch(function () {
                err = true;
            });

        return err === true ? (
            <img
                className="comment-img"
                src={require("../../../../Webroot/images/dashboard/image3.png")}
                alt={firstName + " profile"}
            />
        ) : (
            <img
                className="comment-img"
                src={require("../../../../Webroot/images/dashboard/image4.png")}
                alt={firstName + " profile"}
            />
        );
    };
```

Comment: `try{
   var result = await Axios.get(MY_URL);
   return your success jsx;
} catch(err){
   return your err jsx;
}`

Comment: definitely split your async request from your render, you should make the call seperate and pass the state into the component

Comment: @mahdimahzouni, can you post the proper syntax. If I implement your code after replacing my params, it doesn't work

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane, can you show me some snippet please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not use `.then()` with `async / await` you either use the chainging or the async way.

```
handleProfilePhoto = async (firstName) => {
        let err = false;
      
        try {
           await Axios.get(MY_URL);
        } catch(err) {
           err = true;
        } 
        return err === true ? (
            <img
                className="comment-img"
                src={require("../../../../Webroot/images/dashboard/image3.png")}
                alt={firstName + " profile"}
            />
        ) : (
            <img
                className="comment-img"
                src={require("../../../../Webroot/images/dashboard/image4.png")}
                alt={firstName + " profile"}
            />
        );
    };
```

Also, `handleProfilePhoto` returns an promise.

```
handleProfilePhoto.then(result => {
   //your result is here
})
```

Comment: I get an error. it says `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @Chilarai where do you import this component

Comment: Inside `render(){return .....Rest Of The Code... this. handleProfilePhoto(items.firstname)}` like this. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Actually I have to show profile images of users inside a list view. So, I am calling this function to retrieve the images of the respective users

Comment: @Chilarai the function returns an promise ,you need to resolve it first

Comment: @Chilarai https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242378/rendering-react-components-with-promises-inside-the-render-method

Comment: Ok I will take a look